# Onchange method not working on changing value of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

there is selectbox that this selectbox change the value and attribute of textbox based on each case selected. and a div that named add record to adding new record. the problem is when a new record added the codes for changing textbox not works for new record.is there a way to fix it?
here is my codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_new").click(function() {
    $(".myform")
    .eq(0)
    .clone()
    .insertAfter(".myform:last")
    .show();
  });
});
$(function(){
  $('select[name=type]').change(function(){
    var $option = $(this).find(":selected");
    $(this).siblings('input.to_validate').attr('pattern', $option.attr('data-pattern'));
    $(this).siblings('input.to_validate').attr('placeholder', $option.attr('data-placeholder'));
    $(this).siblings('input.to_validate').attr('title', $option.attr('data-title'));
  });
});
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; 
  border-color: #ff1050 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" class="myform">
<div>
<select name="type">
    <option value="NS" data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong!">NS </option>
    <option value="SRV" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong!">MX </option>
  </select>

<input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Value"  class="to_validate" value="" />

<button type="submit">submit</button>
</div>
</form>
<div class="add_new">ADD Record</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already bound event is not visible for the new added elements. In your case you can bind to the `document`'s event. When you add event to `document`, it will fire also for new added elements by script.  `$(document).on('change', 'select[name=type]', function(){ });`

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add_new").click(function() {
    $(".myform")
      .eq(0)
      .clone()
      .insertAfter(".myform:last")
      .show();
  });
});
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', 'select[name=type]', function() {
    var $option = $(this).find(":selected");
    $(this).siblings('input.to_validate').attr('pattern', $option.attr('data-pattern'));
    $(this).siblings('input.to_validate').attr('placeholder', $option.attr('data-placeholder'));
    $(this).siblings('input.to_validate').attr('title', $option.attr('data-title'));
  });
});
```

```css
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ff1050 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" class="myform">
  <div>
    <select name="type">
      <option value="NS" data-pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])" data-placeholder="Hostname" data-title="Wrong!">NS</option>
      <option value="SRV" data-pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" data-placeholder="IP address" data-title="Wrong!">MX</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Value" class="to_validate" value="" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="add_new">ADD Record</div>
```